# How to persistent oauth login info?

Tags: oauth

I am developing a thrid api client for a website.It use oath

Now How can I only let my app user login one time.

I want to persistent oauth info in session , how to?

Becase every time you use app, you have to login into offical website.it boring.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on service you are using. For example twitter requres you to use "authentication url" ( https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate ) instead of "authorization url". Facebook uses 2.0 version with javascript so there is not problem with that - you have to include offline_access as permission.

In Google Data API I'm not sure yet.